# Run .R functions via CMD - missing execute all command?

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd

Good day,

I want to automate data cleaning and merging via R. I have created multiple folders to which you upload excel files. Than with R I clean the data and merge them to a final file.

I would like to do this process without running R or Rstudio. To accomplish this I run R via CMD (.bat), however, the code does not run.

In my R script I have multiple functions calling from other files, I assume that I need a simple "Run all command" to execute the code via CMD?

Example of Combine_all_excel_files.R

```
setwd("C:\\Code source\\")
source("Seperate_input_folder_by_years.R")
Seperate_input_folder_by_years()
```

Merge data.bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Code source\Combine_all_excel_files.R"
pause
```

When I run the .bad file, the code does not run. What I am doing wrong?

[image: CMD Output]

Comment: If you're using `Start`, why not use it's `/D` option to set the working directory?

Comment: I indicated the full path of the file, so I think the working directory is not a necessary attribute. I found the answer in another thread, it turned out that I indicated Rscript.exe as, however, had to indicate R.exe. Now it works.